# In Zaqar, does a claim extend the TTL?

Tags: message-queue

With **Zaqar**, imagine you have a message `M` in a queue `Queue`.

Let `Queue.claim_timeout == Queue.message_ttl` (please ignore the misuse of the terminology, but also feel free to correct).

Imagine I do a `claim(M)` and I do **no delete**!

**What happens when the `claim_timeout` will be reached?**

1. `M` is still available

   - that means the `message_ttl` was "suspended" while the message was claimed
2. `M` is autodeleted

   - because of the `message_ttl` which will also be reached
3. Something else.

Any explanation or comment will be of huge help.

Thanks,
Costin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seams that the answer is **1**:

> **`M` is still available**
>   ; that means the message_ttl was "suspended" while the message was claimed

I base my statement on the Zaqar docs: https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Zaqar/specs/api/v1#Claims

> The server will extend the lifetime of claimed messages to be at least as long as the lifetime of the claim itself, plus a specified grace period to deal with crashed workers (up to 1209600 or 14 days including claim lifetime). If a claimed message would normally live longer than the grace period, it's expiration will not be adjusted.